# Monotouch - Getting notified when network status changed

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin

I'm familiar with the "reachability" class to check if there is an internet connection:
https://github.com/xamarin/monotouch-samples/blob/master/ReachabilitySample/reachability.cs

I was now wondering if there is any way to get notified when the Network status has changed?
Let's say that my collection is loaded when there is no internet. The images will not get loaded. I would like to trigger the download again if the iPad suddenly gets internet connection again.

In the reachability class, I see following code:

```cs
public static event EventHandler ReachabilityChanged;

    static void OnChange (NetworkReachabilityFlags flags)
    {
        var h = ReachabilityChanged;
        if (h != null)
            h (null, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
```

However, if I set a breakpoint in the "OnChange" method, it's not called when I switch off Wifi.

Any ideas?

Regards, Matt

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, I should have find the answer myself actually.

You should call following functions first before you will be notified:

```
Reachability.InternetConnectionStatus (); 
Reachability.LocalWifiConnectionStatus ();
Reachability.RemoteHostStatus ();
```

Calling these 3 static function calls will initialize all the necessary objects. Those 3 objects will get notified when there is a change and call "OnChange" in the Reachability call (which notifies your Event Handler).

(off course, even better is to create a special function which initialize all the needed objects so you don't need to call these 3 functions as they will really test the network connection already)

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to simply add an event handler to the ReachabilityChanged event, something like (the not test compiled);

```cs
Reachability.ReachabilityChanged += c_ReachabilityChanged;

static void c_ReachabilityChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Here I can handle that network reachability changed.");
}
```

Comment: I know how to add an Event Handler, but the breakpoint is never called in "OnChange", so it will also not trigger the Events. I'm testing it on simulator by turning off the Wifi of my laptop and on a device by launching the app, going to settings to turn off Wifi and going back to app. I'm not sure if my test scenario's are good.

Comment: @Matt Sorry, misunderstood what you were asking then probably, and disconnecting the laptop _should_ work for testing. If that class won't work for you, you can [register a broadcast receiver](http://fizzylogic.nl/2013/08/17/xamarin-android-by-example-monitoring-the-network-status/) to monitor network status.

Comment: Not surprised you misunderstood it, because my words were a little bit confusing (I changed it) regarding the Event. The link you provided is for Android (monodroid), not for iOS (monotouch). I bookmarked your link anyway, because I can use it if I would ever port my app to Android :-)

Comment: @Matt Good that you found a solution, and I should stop posting answers while cooking to be a bit less confused ;)

Answer (score 0):

Just calling this would work, can be written in AppDelegate

```
Reachability.RemoteHostStatus ();

Reachability.ReachabilityChanged += ReachabilityChanged;

static void ReachabilityChanged(object sender, EventArgs e){//Do Something};
```